# Python3のデータフレーム型に関しての質問です。

Tags: python, python3, pandas

データの値が5000~15000くらいまであるデータフレームに関して、その中から最大値及び最小値を抜き出したいのですが、df.max()を使うとなぜか10000未満の最大値（9999.9など）が抜き出されてしまいます。df.min()に関しても10000以上の値が抜き出されてしまいます。原因、解決方法を教えていただけると助かります。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: pandasを使ったことが無いので、推測での回答になりますが、`df.max()`や`df.min()`を実行する前に、`df`の何らかのメソッドを呼び出して（または属性を設定して）、条件が絞り込まれているんではないですかね？

Comment: データの型を
 "print(df.dtypes)" 
にて表示してみてください。各列のデータが数値型ではなく、object型だったりしませんか？

Comment: object型になっていました。数値型に直したところうまくいきました！本当にありがとうございました。

Answer (score 2):

(コメントより)

`print(df.dtypes)` を実行したところ、 object 型になっていました。これを、数値型に直したところ、うまく動作しました。

---

(転記者補足)

`pd.to_numeric(df)` などを行うと、DataFrame のデータ型を変更できます。